# Invoke Delegate with Timer Control?

Tags: c#

I am using Invoke delegate with Timer Control and Thread Pool and i am worried about my Application Performance. So is there any other method apart from Timer.

Also my windows application refreshes every 10 sec and memory size increases. What should i do for that to restrict the memory.

Comment: You should release all the resources that are not needed anymore. I.e. if you create any disposable object you should dispose them.

Comment: application refreshes every 10 sec ? what is your app to do such a drastic refresh ? please define more clearer , so we can go deep to your problem

Comment: The first thing you should do is to show some code, I guess. You are not likely to get any good support here unless people can see what kind of code you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please provide **more** details for your problem.
2. `And memory size increases` - This seems your application has memory leak issues..
3. Check that you are not creating new timer control, i.e. you need to reuse the same object instance for single purpose.

Solution that I guess should help you by understanding your question; Check for where you have coded such as

```
myInstanceControl.OnClick += new EventHandler(myInstanceControl_Click);
```

OR

```
myInstanceControl.OnClick += myInstanceControl_Click;
```

If you have such code snippet in the module execute multiple times then there you need to also code to remove the event handler before object is unreferenced from the scope of execution or in the event handler itself. Such as

```
myInstanceControl.OnClick -= new EventHandler(myInstanceControl_Click);
```

OR

```
myInstanceControl.OnClick -= myInstanceControl_Click;
```

Comment: Thanks For U r comments. I have a timer which inializes once only *timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
                    timer.Interval = 10000;
                    timer.Enabled = true;                    
                    timer.Start(); and in the timer tickfunction i does have set of statements for Execution even the timer inilizes only once also on every function i uses GC.Collect() to free memory. But When My Timer_tick function calls suddenely the memory size increses. About my application handles realtime data and it should refresh every 10 sec.

Comment: @RamdasBhosale Can you show us what happens in the Time_tick function code or concept-wise ? (Update/Edit your question for the same :) )